# How to disable bootstrap confirmation click listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-confirmation

I am using javascript to enable confirmation (http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/) as below:

> $ (className).confirmation ({...})

when I click the dom with the given `className` it will trigger the confirmation dialog. I wonder how I can remove this click event through javascript?

Comment: I've never worked with it, took me 10 seconds to find in the documentation you linked to. http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/#methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is use a [built-in method](http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/#methods) from bootstrap confirmation

```
$('#element').confirmation('hide');
```

---

Snippet

```js
$('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation('hide');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-confirmation2/dist/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="confirmation">Confirmation</button>
```